# Is there a cross-compiler implementation of __builtin_ctz in C?

Tags: c, binary

I want to count the number of trailing zeroes in an integer in C. From what I have read, the *fastest* implementation is `__builtin_ctz`, but this is clearly GCC-specific.

Is there an efficient implementation of this function that does not rely on the user compiling it with GCC?

Comment: Short answer: No. But a Google search for `__builtin_ctz` reveals a number of relevant Stack Overflow (and other) posts.

Comment: When aiming for the _fastest_ its clearly that the instruction set, architecture, etc. should be take into consideration; its not that logical to have a thing that is both the fastest AND cross-compiler. There might even be a instruction whose functionality **is** `ctz` for you computer, that case inline assembly might be the fastest.